# node.js and Firebase session control

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, express-session

I am building an app on node.js using firebase as storage.

When logging with this function

`firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(N1,N2).catch(function(error)`

The user successfully logs in but when i open my localhost from another browser the previous user logged in state shows.

I think the session is being overwritten or something like that

please help me here is my server.js file:-

```
const express = require('express');
var assert = require('assert');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
const session = require('express-session');
var OpenTok = require('opentok'),
    opentok = new OpenTok('xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
const FirebaseStore = require('connect-session-firebase')(session);
const firebase = require('firebase');
const ref = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
});

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(session({resave: false, saveUninitialized: true, secret:'xxxxxx'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

express()
  .use(session({
    store: new FirebaseStore({
      database: ref.database()
    }),
    secret: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  }));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
        if(user){
            res.redirect("/admin");
            console.log(user.email);
        } 
        else {
            res.render('index2.ejs');   
        }
        }); 
});
```

I used this package **Connect Session Firebase** to debug, do something but it didn't help if I m doing anything wrong please tell.

the login code

```
app.post('/signin',function (req, res){
    var N1 = req.body.N1_in;
    var N2 = req.body.N2_in;

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(N1,N2).catch(function(error) {
        }); 
        function function1() {
            // stuff you want to happen right away

        }

        function function2() {
            // all the stuff you want to happen after that pause
            res.redirect('/admin');
        }

        // call the first chunk of code right away
        function1();

        // call the rest of the code and have it execute after 3 seconds
        setTimeout(function2, 2500);
});
```

Comment: Another browser, do you mean chrome to another chrome browser? or chrome to mozilla browser?

Comment: chrome to mozilla or IE, idk what the reason behind this is.

Comment: You will encounter quota limitations if you are using your backend server to sign in users as you are doing. You will get eventually the error auth/too-many-requests. You may need to contact Firebase auth to ask them to whitelist you or something.  Also keep in mind the session is in memory only. So if you restart your node.js server, you will lose the previous session.